# How to create circular ripple?

Tags: android, user-interface, ripple

I want to create similar ripple effect which is shown in red box and is indicated with an arrow.

[image]

Whenever I set *selectableItemBackground* to any element, it just displays ripple over the element's layout bounds, and not like the one I have shared above.

Please share a working example. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#selectableItemBackgroundBorderless) instead of `selectableItemBackground`.

Comment: Tried even that, didn't helped. I set it to background attribute. It just show ripple over the element's layout.

Comment: @Ali_Waris Strange, this attribute should make the ripple effect extend past the bounds of the view. It could possibly be the container `ViewGroup` clipping the background resource. Try setting the [`android:clipChildren`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren) attribute to `false` on the parent `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Only one concern, it won't work below API 21. But, this was what exactly what I was looking for. If you can help me with the backward SDK compatibility, I would be grateful.

Comment: @Ali_Waris Unfortunately the ripple effect is not supported on anything below API level 21. There is an attribute in the [v7 appcompat library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v7-appcompat), but it does not back-port the ripple effect. Instead it just degrades to avoid crashing (to apply the support library attribute use `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless` instead of `?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`).

Comment: @Ali_Waris The only way to apply a ripple effect on a lower platform version would be to code it yourself or use a third-party library (a [quick search](https://google.com#q=android+ripple+library) will lead you to a few).

Answer (score 2):

use **actionBarItemBackground** value for **background**

```
android:background="?android:attr/actionBarItemBackground"
```

Comment: Yes! I've been looking for such a straightforward way of doing this for 8 years now!

Answer (score 0):

android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewCancel"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_x"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/lineTopHorizontal"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/lineVerticalStart" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create simple ripple drawable file:

/res/drawable/transparent_ripple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#77333333" />
```

Comment: Yes, It won't. Ripple effect is available only for 5.0+ Older versions aren't optimized for this animation. You can have ripple drawable in folder `drawable-v21` and simple drawable with `selector` in `drawable` folder. Or you can try to find some library, that will help you with backporting.